# PhoneGap Camera - Cannot press accept button after take a picture

Tags: cordova, android-camera

I have a very strange problem. This problem is not happen when I run it as android application with eclipse (it still run(debug?) on my phone, not virtual device). It just happen when I export app to apk file and install it on my phone. The problem is I cannot press the accept button after take a photo with camera. When I press the accept button, nothing happen, no error, no force close, it just nothing happen.

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(c_onSuccess, c_onFail, { quality: 90,
    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL
});
```

Permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
```